# Switching the highlight color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code which highlights the selected table cell in green color by default.

I am seeking help with a function where there will be three buttons for three different colors, so when I click one of these buttons, the default highlight color will change to that selected color. I have fiddle here too : https://jsfiddle.net/eLb9x2pp/
Any help will be appreciated, I am not very familiar with javascript.

HTML:

```
 <div id="Content">

  <div class="column">
    <div>20</div>
    <div>60</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>72</div>
    <div>71</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>88</div>
    <div>87</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>64</div>
    <div>53</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>90</div>
    <div>79</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>54</div>
    <div>73</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>74</div>
    <div>63</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>98</div>
    <div>57</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>74</div>
    <div>63</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column {
  float: left;
}

.selectedCell {
  background-color: #3ADF00;
}

.column div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  function update_counts() {
    $('#status').html('');
    $('.column').each(function(index) {
      $('#status').html($('#status').html() + $(this).find('.selectedCell').length + ' selected cells in column ' + (index + 1) + '<br />');
    });
  }

  $('.column div').click(function() {
    // Add or remove class
    $(this).toggleClass('selectedCell');
    // Update the class counts
    update_counts();
  });

  // Run the function on domready
  $(function() {
    update_counts();
  });
}); //]]>
```

Comment: Use document.ready function instead of window.load, it will work in fiddle.
Refer the https://jsfiddle.net/16f5axmp/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions. I got my answer on [daniweb.com](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/509634/changing-highlight-colors#post2225976). 
Here it is:

you can use plain javascript:

```
// variables
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_colors');
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.column > div');
var current_color = document.getElementById('green').getAttribute('data-color');
// listener for button clicks
for (let i = 0, c = buttons.length; i < c; i++)
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', set_color, {
    passive: false
  });
// listener for number cells
for (let i = 0, c = numbers.length; i < c; i++)
  numbers[i].addEventListener('click', set_bg, {
    passive: false
  });
// functions
function set_color(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  current_color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
}
function set_bg(event) {
  if(this.classList.contains('clicked'))
  {
    this.classList.remove('clicked');
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    return ;
  }
  this.style.backgroundColor = current_color;
  this.classList.add('clicked');
}
```

And in the HTML part just add data-color="COLOR" and class="btn_colors" to the buttons, where COLOR is the name or the code to assign to the backgroundColor property:

```
<p>
    <input class="btn_colors" data-color="#007FFF" type="button" name="blue" id="blue" value="Blue" />
    <input class="btn_colors" data-color="#F2B400" type="button" name="yellow" id="yellow" value="Yellow" />
    <input class="btn_colors" data-color="#66B447" type="button" name="green" id="green" value="Green" />
</p>
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/tsLgtzkv/

In your case, in your example you were not loading JQuery, and not setting to run on onDomready. In my example there is no dependency, but it should run in the body, after all the HTML, to allow the browser to complete the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function and set the style in css using javascript

```
function changeHiglight(someColorCode){
    var yourItem = document.getElementyById("urItemId");
    yourItem.style.background-color = someColorCode;
}
```

just give it a color code or a status and set the Color depending on the status

well its a rookie idea, but better then nothing

Comment: I did this in the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/r94m7o8c/ Now highlighting is not working at all. can you guide me where I m doing wrong?  please. thanks.